# Как дать значение определённому слову из текстовика

Tags: python

Я знаю что название звучит ужасно, но на практике надеюсь это легче. Моя проблема заключается в том что я не знаю как дать значение опреденному слову. К тому же, у меня их 2. И так, у меня в͟ ͟б͟л͟о͟к͟н͟о͟т͟е͟ 2 слова, первое это набор букв и чисел (например: 1324weaw56sges3) и через \n (ENTER) у меня номер телефона (например: +77777777777). Выглядит это так:

```
1324weaw56sges3
+777777777777
```

Мне нужно получить их под свои значением, например:

```
token = 1324weaw56sges3
phone = +777777777777
```

Так вот, как при открытие блокнота, выдать им определение "token" и "phone". Я пытался так, но дальше я не знаю что делать:

```
f = open("settings.txt", 'r')
token = f.read().split("\n")
f.close()
for i in token:
    print(i)
```

И на выводе я просто получу их как в блокноте, но как выдать им определение я так и не понял. Жду гения :)

Comment: Что print(i) выводит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл можно читать постепенно по строкам

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
   token = f.readline().rstrip('\n')
   phone = f.readline().rstrip('\n')

print(token, phone)
```

Или же ваш код можно преобразовать к следующему виду:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    token, phone = f.read().split('\n')[:2]

print(token, phone)
```